# Magento homepage has conflict only on the index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

We have made some changes on our homepage and it all went fine until we clicked to get to the homepage... Which is somehow different.

Example: http://www.testsite.net <- this one is fine with the jQuery and Javascript together.

Example: http://www.testsite.net/index.php <- this one doesn't work with jQuery and Javascript together.

I have no idea why it doesn't work only on index.php...
My question is, why doesn't this work? Is there something special I need to know?
Do you have any suggestions? A workaround maybe?

I can post some code but it's kind of a pain to do that because it's quite alot.
If you want some code, please state what kind of code you need...

Any more information needed? Feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi i can tell you a suggestion.Go to your magento database and got to "core_config_data" table.If your tables have a prefix then it should be in "prefixcore_config_data" format.Then check "path" column.There you can see one row call "web/unsecure/base_url" and other raw call "web/secure/base_url".Change both rows "value" column's value to your website's base url.In your case it should be "http://www.testsite.net". And make sure your server's rewrite module is on and htaccess has allow "http://www.testsite.net" to be loaded without "http://www.testsite.net/index.php". Hope this will help you.

Comment: @BuddhiEash I see that the value is already testsite.net I took a look in our .htaccess in our root directory, and it said something like this (don't know if I'm looking at the right thing):`############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to search in jquery and javascript code if you find your static url "http://www.testsite.net"  then you need to make dynamic with location.hostname